# Salvar formulário com NodeJS e MySQL

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, express.js

Sou leigo no mundo de Node.JS e estou desenvolvendo um formulário em que o número de campos é dinâmico, ou seja, existe um botão que chama uma função no JavaScript que vai adicionando campos de acordo com a necessidade do usuário.

Meu problema está em capturar esse "*array*" de campos e passar de forma correta para minha função de salvar de modo em que todo o conteúdo seja inserido na base de dados.

Código HTML do formulário:

```
<html>
<body>
  <form action="/boletim/salvar" method="post">
    <div class="formulario">
      <div class="input-group control-group">
        <input type="text" name="data_evento" class="form-control" id="datetime" placeholder="Data do evento">
      </div>
      <div class="input-group control-group  col-md-4">
        <input type="text" name="titulo_evento" class="form-control" placeholder="Título do evento">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="copy-fields hide">
      <div class="control-group">
        <div class="input-group" style="margin-top:10px">
          <input type="text" name="data_evento" class="form-control calendar" placeholder="Data do evento" id="datetime" onmouseover="calendario()">
        </div>
        <div class=" input-group col-md-4">
          <input type="text" name="titulo_evento" class="form-control" placeholder="Título do evento">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group-btn after-add-more">
          <button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Função JavaScript (*front-end*):

```
//Adiciono a div que contem os campos
$(".add-more").click(function () {
    var html = $(".copy-fields").html();
    $(".copy-fields").before(html);
    //$(".formulario").after(html);

});
//Removo a div que contem os campos que foram adicionados
$("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {
    $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
});

$("#datetime").datetimepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii",
    autoclose: true
});
```

Módulo de salvar (*back-end*):

```
module.exports.salvar = function(application,req,res){

var connection = application.config.dbConnection();
  var boletimModel= new application.app.models.BoletimDAO(connection); 

var info_boletim = req.body;

boletimModel.salvarEventos(info_boletim,function(error, result){
  res.redirect('/');
}); 
}
```

Conteúdo que o módulo "*salvar*" está recebendo:

```
{ data_evento: [ '2018-03-01 23:50', '2018-03-02 07:35', '' ],
  titulo_evento: [ 'Conteudo do primeiro campo', 'conteudo do segundo campo', '' ] }
```

Alguma sugestão da melhor forma pra resolver este problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver desta forma:

```
module.exports.salvar = function (application, req, res) {

var connection = application.config.dbConnection();
var boletimModel = new application.app.models.BoletimDAO(connection);

qtd = req.body.data_evento.length;

    for (i = 0; i < qtd - 1; i++) {
        data = req.body.data_evento[i];
        titulo = req.body.titulo_evento[i];

        var info_boletim = { data_evento: data, titulo_evento: titulo };

        boletimModel.salvarEventos(info_boletim, function (error, result) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Erro ao inserir no banco de dados");
            }
        });
    }
    res.redirect('/');
 }
```